# Problem in creating dataframe in logistic regression model

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, prediction

I am having trouble in creating a data frame for a logistic regression model and extracting results in Excel similar to SAS. I have the following data in the top 4 rows:

```r
dose       location   gender   Damage
9.000000  locationA   Male    0.4488765
9.000000  locationB   Female  0.1326636
9.151515  locationA   Male    0.4572672
9.151515  locationB  Female   0.1366086
```

Here it is creating a result for only location A: Male and location B: Female. But there are males and females in both location, I should have 4 values for 9.00000 and so on.....

Here is my condition:

I have data with 5 doses (x-axis) and the response is damage (binary: 0, 1). I want to check the model fit in two locations, each with male and female data. I split my data into `testData` and `trainData` (0.80). My model fit looks like this::

```r
Model <- glm(Damage ~., data = trainData, family = binomial)

new_data <- data.frame(location = c('locationA', 'locationB'),
                       gender = c('Male', 'Female'),
                       dose = rep(seq(9, 24, length.out = 100), 4))
```

Comment: When creating `new_data` use the function `expand.grid` instead of `data.frame` but with all the same arguments. This will give you both locations with both sexes at each value of `dose`

Comment: Greetings and welcome to SO! In the future, you should provide some reproducible data so others can help. It's difficult for others to retrace your steps and create solutions if they don't even know what your original data looks like. I've provided my own simulated data to get around this, but just keep in mind that this is a lot of work on the answerer's part and minimizes the chances you will get answers to your questions here. An easy way around this is running `dput(trainData)` and pasting the output into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your new_data only has two groups:

```
> table(new_data$location, new_data$gender)  
           
            Female Male
  locationA      0  200
  locationB    200    0
```

Try this:

```
new_data <- data.frame(location = c('locationA', 'locationB'),
                         gender = c('Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female'),
                         dose = rep(seq(9, 24, length.out = 100), 4))

> table(new_data$location, new_data$gender)  
           
            Female Male
  locationA    100  100
  locationB    100  100
```

Comment: It helped, still I am having problem in final  result by doing so its giving me same vale for Male in both location or female in both location                                                                             9.000000   locationA    Male     0.22619457
9.000000   locationB     Male     0.22619457
9.000000   locationA     Female   0.04454353
9.000000   locationB      Female   0.04454353

Answer (score 0):

### Unique Value Problem

The bigger problem with both your data and the data from the other answer here is that both are assigning the same genders to the same groups, so there is no unique estimable variance between gender and location. This would be pretty bizarre for real data anyway and wouldn't provide really useful information in a new prediction. Better would be to create randomized data that can provide useful outcomes. Additionally, since you and the other answer didn't have train data to work with (that' up to OP to provide a minimally reproducible dataset and not the answerers), it's difficult to reproduce what you did. I have simulated some data, and the way I simulate this data is also how I will simulate the prediction data, so this should hopefully make it clear what I'm doing.

### Simulating Train Data

First, simulating the data. I will create the values both of you attempted already so we have data to sample from.

```
#### Create Data to Sample From ####
set.seed(123)
location.names <- c("Location A", "Location B")
gender.names <- c("Male","Female")
dose.names <- rep(seq(9, 24, length.out = 100), 4)
```

Then I set a seed to initiate a random number generator, which makes the simulation reproducible. Thereafter I use `sample` to sample from our simulated data 1000 times **at random**. This achieves two things: 1) our data is truly random 2) we are not binning all the males in one location and all the females in another location. I also use `rbinom` to create binary data, which you won't be using when creating the test data. Finally you merge it all into a data frame and inspect the first 10 rows with `head`.

```
#### Train Data ####
set.seed(123)
location <- sample(location.names, size = 1000, replace = T)
gender <- sample(gender.names, size = 1000, replace = T)
dose <- sample(dose.names, size = 1000, replace = T)
damage <- rbinom(n=1000, size = 1, prob = .5)
train <- data.frame(location,
                         gender,
                         dose,
                         damage)
head(train, 10)
```

### Fit Model

Fit the regression as always. Here I specify the variables explicitly:

```
#### Fit Model ####
fit <- glm(damage ~ location + gender + dose,
           data = train,
           family = binomial)
summary(fit)
```

The results are below:

```
Call:
glm(formula = damage ~ location + gender + dose, family = binomial, 
    data = train)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-1.193  -1.167  -1.141   1.187   1.215  

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)         0.028239   0.258970   0.109    0.913
locationLocation B -0.030834   0.126629  -0.243    0.808
genderMale          0.041228   0.126586   0.326    0.745
dose               -0.003552   0.014445  -0.246    0.806

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1386.2  on 999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1385.9  on 996  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1393.9

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

### Creating Test Data

We essentially just do the same exact thing we did before, only this time we are creating 50 new data points to merge into a test data set called `new.data`.

```
#### Create New Data ####
location <- sample(location.names, size = 50, replace = T)
gender <- sample(gender.names, size = 50, replace = T)
dose <- sample(dose.names, size = 50, replace = T)

new.data <- data.frame(location,
                       gender,
                       dose)
head(new.data, 10)
```

From there you use `predict` to generate predictions:

```
#### Predict ####
predict(fit,
        newdata = new.data)
```

Shown below:

```
            1             2             3             4             5 
-0.0074969847 -0.0039422100 -0.0098622565 -0.0062520979 -0.0109386286 
            6             7             8             9            10 
-0.0706218955 -0.0803092442 -0.0444633069 -0.0349444729  0.0267343944 
           11            12            13            14            15 
 0.0018206928 -0.0652400350 -0.0684691513 -0.0147059309 -0.0460778651 
           16            17            18            19            20 
-0.0392499613 -0.0202449350 -0.0039422100  0.0191997898 -0.0077095123 
           21            22            23            24            25 
-0.0381735892 -0.0121721443  0.0105888132 -0.0017894658 -0.0039422100 
           26            27            28            29            30 
-0.0365590311 -0.0533999421 -0.0455396790 -0.0193370777 -0.0415598491 
           31            32            33            34            35 
-0.0177225195 -0.0404834770 -0.0017894658 -0.0733128257 -0.0351016166 
           36            37            38            39            40 
-0.0085733568  0.0208143480  0.0025160225 -0.0263334962 -0.0197067489 
           41            42            43            44            45 
-0.0220280079 -0.0770801280  0.0002061346 -0.0069587987 -0.0521664263 
           46            47            48            49            50 
 0.0105888132  0.0089742550 -0.0351016166  0.0084360690  0.0057451388
```

### Using One Predictor

It looks like in the comments you were interested in just predictions for one predictor on the outcome. This is quite simple. Just specify new data with one variable instead.

```
#### Use Just one Variable ####
new.data <- data.frame(dose)
head(new.data, 10)

#### Predict ####
predict(fit,
        newdata = new.data)
```

Which gives new predictions based off only the single variable:

```
           1            2            3            4            5 
-0.020413450 -0.084614733 -0.033161400 -0.060396361 -0.068469151 
           6            7            8            9           10 
-0.057010101 -0.001408423 -0.041402705 -0.051785384 -0.014324889 
          11           12           13           14           15 
-0.067392779 -0.040326333 -0.087305663 -0.040483477 -0.038868919 
          16           17           18           19           20 
 0.020814348  0.001439650 -0.035482659 -0.012340659 -0.014324889 
          21           22           23           24           25 
-0.006958799 -0.051247198 -0.032253543 -0.039788147 -0.038543260 
          26           27           28           29           30 
-0.041940891 -0.058243616 -0.023104380 -0.042636221 -0.050170826 
          31           32           33           34           35 
-0.034406287  0.023505278 -0.013955217 -0.050709012  0.006283325 
          36           37           38           39           40 
-0.001789466 -0.019168563 -0.087305663  0.014356115 -0.045865337 
          41           42           43           44           45 
-0.085152919 -0.005713912 -0.046616051 -0.081385616 -0.013629559 
          46           47           48           49           50 
-0.073851012  0.001820693 -0.004099354 -0.004099354 -0.057010101
```

To write predictions into a CSV file, you just have to save the object and use `write.csv`.

```
#### Predict ####
pred <- predict(fit,
        newdata = new.data)
write.csv(pred,
          file = "pred.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you, how can you extract this list of complete prediction for each variable in write.csv. For example                                                                                                                           dose       location   gender   Predictions
9.000000  locationA   Male    0.0074969847
9.000000  locationB   Female  0.0706218955                                                                                                 9.000000  location A  Female   0.077080

Comment: I think I missed what you were trying to say. Did you mean that you want predictions for just one predictor and it's response? Like dose x damage? This can be done by just including one predictor into the new data (I've edited my answer to include this). Otherwise it is impossible to do with all the predictors included because there is no meaningful way to extract the fitted/residual data per predictor when all others are entered (the regression already controls for the effect of the other predictors).

Comment: Oh wait, you mean you just want to write the prediction data into a csv?

Comment: My comment above already highlights that it is impossible to get by-predictor fitted values. You do not get a unique fitted value for each, otherwise they would all be simple regressions, not multiple linear regression.

Comment: How would you calculate 10% or .......% lethal dose for location A on female? Here is a small portion of my data, I don't know how to attach as excel sheet                                         Damage Dose location gender
0 9 LCA Male
1 9 LCA Male
0 9 LCA Male
1 9 LCA Male
0 9 LCA Male
0 9 LCA Male
1 9 LCB  Male
1 9 LCB  Male
1 9 LCB  Male
0 9 LCB  Male
0 9 LCB  Male
0 9 LCB  Male
0 9 LCA Female
0 9 LCA Female
0 9 LCA Female
0 9 LCA Female
0 9 LCA Female
0 9 LCA Female
0 9 LCB  Female
0 9 LCB  Female
0 9 LCB  Female
0 9 LCB  Female
0 9 LCB  Female
0 9 LCB  Female

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question....the answerers here have already expended effort trying to answer your original question, and you should either upvote or accept an answer if they already satisfied your request (I believe I already have, but that is for you to decide). Additionally, asking a bunch of follow-up questions clogs up the comments if they're not related to the original problem. Note that I left a comment under Alan's that `dput` is a valuable way to share your data rather than copy pasting tables into comments, which most people won't be able to read.